# Why Javascript waits for promises to fulfil

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

I'm learning promises and I came across this piece of code

```
async function main() {
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("hello");
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
  console.log("world");
}

main();
```

The output this produces is "hello world".

What I'm not able to understand is why the inner console log "console.log("world")" is waiting for the promise to resolve.

Am I missing something here, it would be nice if I can get some help understanding this or maybe some link to some documentation for further reading.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because you're awaiting the promise?

Comment: This is how async/await works. Check [MDN asyn function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function); For further reading, try [You-Dont-Know-JS/Chap4](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/async%20%26%20performance/ch4.md)

Answer (score 0):

> Am I missing something here

Bluntly speaking yes, you're missing first word of the second line.
The key to understand what's happen there is `await`.
You're creating a promise with

```js
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("hello");
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
```

This promise will start an asynchronous action, that could end somewhere in the future (after 1 sec in this particular case).
You probably supposed that this action should be executed after `console.log("world");` and it could happen if there was no `await` before promise.
But we do have this `await` so we litteraly said to program "Hey, I want to wait for this action to end, before I'll go farther".
That's why we see printed `hello` before `world`.

Answer (score 0):

> Await expressions make promise-returning functions behave as though
> they're synchronous by suspending execution until the returned promise
> is fulfilled or rejected.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#description)

Let's break this down step-by-step without overcomplicating things. This is what is happening inside your `main()` function:

1. the first line is executed as expected, but the keyword `await` inside your function stops the progress (the promise must be first fulfilled or rejected)
2. inside the promise you have `setTimout()`, another asynchronous function, but this one is not awaited;

> setTimeout() is an asynchronous function, meaning that the timer
> function will not pause execution of other functions in the functions
> stack. In other words, you cannot use setTimeout() to create a "pause"
> before the next function in the function stack fires.
> [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#working_with_asynchronous_functions)

Yet, the execution seems to be paused, but it is not due to `setTimeout()` function on its own. It is because the promise waits to be resolved. And when do we resolve it? After 1 second.

4. The callback inside `setTimeout()` is executed as expected: `console.log('hello')` is printed first and the promise is resolved right after with `resolve()`.
5. With the promise being resolved, the progress finally continues with the `console.log('world')`.

Thus we end up with

```
 // hello
 // world
```

You can try moving the `resolve()` outside of the `setTimeout()` and observe how the promise is resolved right away and the printed message is reversed (because, as I said above, `setTimout()` does not pause the execution of the promise on its own).

```
async function main() {
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('hello')
  }, 1000)
  resolve()
})
console.log('world')
}

// world
// hello
```

To wrap it up:

> What I'm not able to understand is why the inner console log >"console.log("world")" is waiting for the promise to resolve.

The `console.log("world")` is not waiting for the promise, it is waiting for the delay inside `setTimeout()`. Just as promise is waiting to be resolved: which happens right after the `console.log("world")`.

Answer (score -2):

Because this is how promises work. They are designed to always return a clear result. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise for more info.